# jquery nested sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I have been using [NestedSortabe from b-hind](http://www.b-hind.eu/jquery/) and found it quite useful until I upgraded to latest jquery and jquery-ui I guess they changed the way mouse events are handled or something to that effect. Point it the nestedSortable doesn't work any longer.

So my question is tri fold

does anyone know if the folks at jquery have implemented a nested sortable I haven't seen anything.

or does anyone know how to fix the b-hind version

or know of something better / light weight to accomplish the same goals

would like something compatible with lastest jquery-ui

**EDIT:** it appears as though the lastest version of jquery-ui-sortable supports nested sorting

**EDIT EDIT** well sort of you can't drop on items that don't have ul's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently [developed a plugin](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable) which works pretty much like the one from b-hind (i.e. creates nested `<ul>` on the fly), but written for UI 1.8+.

Comment: that looks nice I'll play around with it.. I did notice one thing that it does that I don't like.. it puts a style tag in the html design should always be separated it should just have a another class added instead bot other than that, so far; looks good

Comment: Actually that's Sortable that uses the style attribute. It's the only way because, for example, the height of the placeholder depends on the height of the item moved, and there is no way to know that before!